# Unable to test a static method using NUnit framework

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to use NUnit to test the methods (in this case Tick() ) in a static class Clock but it simply returns an error stating that that method does not exist in the namespace. I have made sure to use the same namespace for my source project and my NUnit test as well as adding a reference of the NUnit test to the source code and `using NUnit.Framework;`

Static class Clock:

```
namespace Clock
{
    static class Clock
    {
        private static Counter[] _counters;

        static Clock()
        {
            _counters = new Counter[3];
            _counters[0] = new Counter("Second counter");
            _counters[1] = new Counter("Minute counter");
            _counters[2] = new Counter("Hour counter");
        }

        public static void Tick()
        {
            _counters[0].Increment(); 

            if (_counters[0].Ticks == 60)
            {
                _counters[0].Reset();
                _counters[1].Increment();
            }

            if (_counters[1].Ticks == 60)
            {
                _counters[1].Reset();
                _counters[2].Increment(); 
            }

            if (_counters[2].Ticks == 24)
            {
                _counters[2].Reset();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to use `Clock.Tick()` in NUnit test, the error occured:

```
      [Test]
        public void TestTick()
        {
            Clock.Tick();
            Assert.AreEqual(1, Clock.GetCounter(0).Ticks); 
            Assert.AreEqual(0, Clock.GetCounter(1).Ticks); 
            Assert.AreEqual(0, Clock.GetCounter(2).Ticks); 
        }
```

Specific Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Tick' does not exist in the namespace 'Clock' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  NUnitTest

Comment: Try `public static class Clock` and then `Clock.Clock.Tick();`.

Answer (score 3):

puts public in front of static, it cannot be access by its protection level

Comment: oh, it works, that's simple. Thank you but I do have one question. Can you explain why my main method can access Clock Static Class but my NUnit can not?